# Bad request error unit test multipart spring rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have the next unit test define to test a controller which is used to upload files:

```
 public class PhenotypeControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest{

        private MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
                Charset.forName("utf8"));

        @Before
        public void setup() throws Exception {
            super.setup();
        }

        @Test
        public void loadPhenotype_success() throws Exception{
            //mock uuid generation
            UUID idFile = UUID.randomUUID();
             //Generate the response
             ResponseLoad resp = new ResponseLoad();
             resp.setFileIdentifier(idFile);
             resp.setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
             resp.setDescription(null);

             MockMultipartFile phenoFile  = new MockMultipartFile("size_trans_20160419_KM2.txt","size_trans_20160419_KM2.txt", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.toString(), new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/size_trans_20160419_KM2.txt"));
             mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/phenotypes/load")
                                    .file(phenoFile))
                                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                    .andExpect(content().contentType(this.contentType))
                                    .andExpect(content().json(json(resp)));
        }
    }
```

The super class of the test contains the annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.test.properties")
public abstract class BaseControllerTest {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

     @Autowired
    void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters) {

        this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = Arrays.asList(converters).stream()
            .filter(hmc -> hmc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);

        assertNotNull("the JSON message converter must not be null",
                this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
     }

     public void setup() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
     }

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected String json(Object o) throws IOException {
        MockHttpOutputMessage mockHttpOutputMessage = new MockHttpOutputMessage();
        this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.write(
                o, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, mockHttpOutputMessage);
        return mockHttpOutputMessage.getBodyAsString();
    }
}
```

When I run test I get an 400 error but other tests which uses a non multipart request works fine.The controller method is like:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Load Phenotype File", nickname = "loadPhenotype",
        tags = {"Phenotypes"} )
        @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Nice!", response = Response.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 507, message = "Error uploading files")
        })
@PostMapping(value="/phenotypes/load", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseLoad> uploadPhenotype(
        @ApiParam(value="Phenotype File", required=true) 
        @RequestPart(required = true) MultipartFile file){
    //1. Validate parameters
    ResponseLoad response = new ResponseLoad();
    response.setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
    //2. Copy file to /tmp/SNPaware/phenotypes/tmp/<UUID>.pheno
    response.setFileIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID());
    logger.info("Storage phenotype file with identifier "+response.getFileIdentifier());
    storageService.store(file, "tmp/"+response.getFileIdentifier()+".pheno");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

}

And it works correctly when I send a request to the rest api like this:

> curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header
>   'Accept: application/json' {"type":"formData"}
>   'http://hippo:9087/phenotypes/load'

Why I am receiving a 400 in the test? Am I missing some configuration on the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of the multipartFile in the test. The original name should match the name of the parameter in the controller, in this case file.

This definition solve the problem:

```
 MockMultipartFile phenoFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "size_trans_20160419_KM2.txt", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.toString(), new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/size_trans_20160419_KM2.txt"));
```

Comment: @jannis I can not mark the answer as accepted until tomorrow because I answer my own question (a restriction of stackoverflow).

Comment: Yep, I didn't know that. Makes sense